# how to sort query result in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below is my query and i want to sort this query by description i.e with field ld.descrip. where to use order by in below query to sort data according to description.

```
Select ld.fact_code as costFactorID,ld.fact_code + ' ' + ld.descrip +' ' +'(' + convert(varchar,cast(ld.factor as money),1)+ '/' + ld.unit + ')' as costFactor, ap.alpha_code, ap.code, ld.neighborhd,ap.code
                                        from lndfact ld 
                                        inner join app_lookup ap on ap.code like ld.neighborhd 
                                        inner join parcel p on p.neighborhd = ap.alpha_code 
                                        inner join assessments assmt on assmt.parcel_no = p.parcel_no 
                                        where  assmt.assesmt_no = @0 and ld.value_type = @1
                                        union All
                                        Select ld.fact_code as costFactorID,ld.fact_code + ' ' + ld.descrip +' ' +'(' + convert(varchar,cast(ld.factor as money),1)+ '/' + ld.unit + ')' as costFactor, ap.alpha_code, ap.code, ld.neighborhd,ap.code
                                        from lndfact ld 
                                        inner join app_lookup ap on ap.code like ld.neighborhd and ap.code = 77
```

Comment: You can add at both ends of the select query?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order  by at the end of the united  query  alias in  firts query only , (same number of corresponing type column)

```
  Select 
       ld.fact_code as costFactorID
      ,ld.fact_code + ' ' + ld.descrip +' ' +'(' + convert(varchar,cast(ld.factor as money),1)+ '/' + ld.unit + ')' as costFactor
      , ap.alpha_code
      , ap.code
      , ld.neighborhd
      ,ap.code
  from lndfact ld 
  inner join app_lookup ap on ap.code like ld.neighborhd 
  inner join parcel p on p.neighborhd = ap.alpha_code 
  inner join assessments assmt on assmt.parcel_no = p.parcel_no 
  where  assmt.assesmt_no = @0 and ld.value_type = @1
  union All
  Select 
       ld.fact_code 
      ,ld.fact_code + ' ' + ld.descrip +' ' +'(' + convert(varchar,cast(ld.factor as money),1)+ '/' + ld.unit + ')' 
      , ap.alpha_code
      , ap.code
      , ld.neighborhd
      ,ap.code
  from lndfact ld 
  inner join app_lookup ap on ap.code like ld.neighborhd and ap.code = 77
  ORDER BY alpha_code, code /* eg: */
```